# How to share presenter methods between presenters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to call a presenter method from another presenter in a Rails 4 app. Nothing is being rendered in the view. What is the correct way to set this up?

For example, if I want to display a user presenter within an activity feed, using Ryan Bates examples as a basis

user presenter: http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch

activity feed presenter: http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch

I'm trying to do something like

```
class ActivityPresenter < SimpleDelegator
....
  def render_activity
    div_for activity do
      present action.user do |user_presenter|
        user_presenter.linked_name
      end
    end
  end
...
end

class UserPresenter < BasePresenter
...
  def linked_name
    site_link(user.full_name.present? ? user.full_name : user.username)
  end
...
end
```

The user is not being "presented". What am I doing wrong?

The presenter is initialized with a helper method

```
def present(object, klass = nil)
  klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize
  presenter = klass.new(object, self)
  yield presenter if block_given?
  presenter
end
```

though can also be accessed in the controller:

```
def present(object, klass = nil)
  klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize
  klass.new(object, view_context)
end
```

Enabling render in the view as follows:

```
<% present @user do |user_presenter| %>
    <%= user_presenter.linked_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you using any gem ?

Comment: well, several gems in the app, but none that are being called here or that should be influencing

Comment: Ahh! I meant you are using any gem for presenter pattern ? :)

Comment: no, just a base presenter as per the Railscast

Comment: There are quite a few things missing here for anyone to be able to give a meaningful answer.  How are you initializing the presenters (add the code from your controller)?  How are you outputting the presenter in your view?

Comment: Have you declared a `user.url`? I'm looking at the code from the railscast and the `UserPresenter#site_link` method makes no damn sense.

Comment: @max, yes the presenter works fine in a view. I'm only running into problems when trying to call a presenter within a presenter.

Comment: e.g, if I call the activity presenter by itself, no problem. If I call the user presenter by itself, no problem. But if I try to reuse user presenter outputs within the activity presenter, then I run into problems.